# Using ParametricNDSolve for the Kuramoto model on a random graph

Tags: differential-equations, performance-tuning, graphs-and-networks

I am trying to run the [Kuramoto model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuramoto_model) on a [hyperbolic random geometric graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_geometric_graph). I am plotting the order parameter (amount of synchrony) against coupling strength.

Here is the code:

```
SeedRandom[];
evaltime = 2000;
preludetime = 1000;
nsamples = 10000;
numpoints = 10;
min = 0.01;
max = 3;
numiterations = 1;
\[Nu] = 1;
\[Rho] = 500;
\[Alpha] = 3;
\[Zeta] = 3;
R = 4;
\[Theta]start = 0;
plot[\[Rho]_, r0_] := Module[{},
  \[Theta]start = 0;
  SeedRandom[];
  rg1 = hrgg[\[Rho], r0];
  rg2 = Subgraph[rg1, ConnectedComponents[rg1][[1]], 
    GraphLayout -> "BalloonEmbedding"];
  Print[rg2];
  rg2 = AdjacencyGraph[AdjacencyMatrix[rg2]];
  Nosc = Length@VertexList[rg2];
  gammadisp = 0.05;
  If[\[Theta]start == 0, 
   SeedRandom[]; \[Theta]start = RandomReal[{0, 2*Pi}, Nosc];];
  omegadata = VertexDegree[rg2];
  A = AdjacencyMatrix[rg2];
  B = N[IncidenceMatrix[
     Graph[UpperTriangularize[A]["NonzeroPositions"], 
      DirectedEdges -> True]]];
  X[\[Theta]_?VectorQ, \[Lambda]_] := 
   N[omegadata] - \[Lambda] B . Sin[\[Theta] . B];
  tnonconvex2 = ConstantArray[0, {numpoints, 2}];
  Clear[t1, t2, t3];
  For[i = 1, i <= numpoints, i++,
   a = ParametricNDSolveValue[{\[Theta]'[t] == 
       X[\[Theta][t], \[Lambda]], \[Theta][
        0] == \[Theta]start}, \[Theta], {t, 0, evaltime}, {\[Lambda]}];
   solution = a[((max - min) (i - 1))/numpoints + min];
   Print["done ", i];
   g = rg1;
   samplepoints = 
    Sort@RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{preludetime, evaltime}], 
      nsamples];
   data = 
    Abs[1/Nosc Total[Exp[-I Mean[{solution[#]}]]]] & /@ samplepoints;
   tnonconvex2[[i, 1]] = ((max - min) (i - 1))/numpoints + min;
   tnonconvex2[[i, 2]] = Mean[data];
   \[Theta]start = solution[evaltime];
   Print["I found that ", tnonconvex2[[i, 1 ;; 2]]];
   Print[ListPlot[Transpose[{samplepoints, data}], 
     PlotRange -> {{preludetime, evaltime}, {0, 1}}, 
     Joined -> True]];
   ];
  out = tnonconvex2;]
(*Now the code for creating the hyperbolic random geometric graph*)

hypdistance[x_, y_] := 
  Module[{x1, y1, x2, y2, r1, \[Theta]1, r2, \[Theta]2, c}, 
   x1 = x[[1]];
   y1 = x[[2]];
   x2 = y[[1]];
   y2 = y[[2]];
   polar1 = ToPolarCoordinates[{x1, y1}];
   polar2 = ToPolarCoordinates[{x2, y2}];
   r1 = polar1[[1]];
   r2 = polar2[[1]];
   \[Theta]1 = polar1[[2]];
   \[Theta]2 = polar2[[2]];
   \[Delta] = Pi - Abs[Pi - Abs[\[Theta]1 - \[Theta]2]];
   \[Gamma] = 
    Cosh[\[Zeta] r1] Cosh[\[Zeta] r2] - 
     Sinh[\[Zeta] r1] Sinh[\[Zeta] r2] Cos[\[Delta]];
   1/\[Zeta] ArcCosh[\[Gamma]]];
edges[v1_] := 
  Module[{}, Select[v1, hypdistance[#[[1]], #[[2]]] < R &]];

gr6[vert_] := 
  Graph[vert, UndirectedEdge @@@ edges[Subsets[vert, {2}]], 
   VertexCoordinates -> vert];
d[R_] := 
    ProbabilityDistribution[\[Alpha] Sinh[\[Alpha] r]/(
    Cosh[\[Alpha] R] - 1), {r, 0, R}];
hrgg[\[Rho]_, r0_] := 
  Module[{}, 
   polarpts = 
    Transpose[{RandomVariate[d[r0], \[Rho]], 
      RandomReal[{-Pi, Pi}, \[Rho]]}];
   pts = FromPolarCoordinates[polarpts];
   v = pts;
   graph6 = gr6[v];
   gr1 = graph6; gr1];
(*Run the program*)
plot[\[Rho], R];
(*Output final data synchrony vs coupling*)
ListPlot[tnonconvex2, 
 Joined -> True]
```

For small graphs, with long evaluation times, the code works fine, and even shows the explosive transition that is meant to occur. But for larger graphs, I get an error message:

[image]

After this, the code runs much slower, and even just halts indefinitely.

Are there settings e.g. `MaxSteps` I can use, that avoid this? Or other settings that are appropriate for the `ParametricNDSolve`?